# How to create a table with cycle "for" in json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following html table:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>  </th>
     <th> Monday </th> 
     <th> Tuesday </th> 
     <th> Wednesday</th> 
     <th> Thursday </th> 
     <th> Friday </th>
     <th> Saturday</th> 
   </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> 8:30 - 10:00 </td>
      <td> Math</td>
      <td>Math </td>
      <td>Math</td>
      <td> Math </td>
      <td> Math</td>
      <td> Math</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I create a table like that using only JavaScript?

Comment: Your question is very vague and unanswerable as it stands. You might want to add more detail as to what you're trying to achieve, and to include any attempts you've made already to achieve this yourself to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    var days = {
        "Monday": ["8:30 - 10:00", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math"],
        "Tuesday": [],
        "Wednesday": [],
        "Thursday ": [],
        "Friday": [],
        "Saturday": []

    }

    var html;

    html = "<table><tr>"
    for (var day in days) {

        html += "<th>" + day + "</th>";

    }

    html += "</tr>"
    for (var day in days) {

        if (days[day].length != 0) {
            html += "<tr>"

            for (var i = 0; i < days[day].length; i++) {
                html += "<td>" + days[day][i] + "</td>"
            }
        }

         html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
</script>
```